# Methods to remove specific characters from string?

Tags: php, string

I need to remove the brackets "[" and "]" from `$widget_text` in the variable value below and store the result in `$widget_id`.

```
$widget_text = '[widget_and-some-text]';
$widget_id = ?;
```

Use `preg_replace`, `str_replace` or something else?

Comment: Michiel's answer will get you done, but do you wish to do any verification on the string?

Comment: @Col. S: Thanks for the helpful advice, sans crap ;-)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There are several methods available, and they can sometimes be made to perform exactly the same task, like preg_replace/str_replace. But, perhaps you want to remove brackets only from the beginning or end of the string; in which case preg_replace works. But, if there could be several brackets, preg_replace can do the job too. But trim is easier and makes more sense.

**preg_replace()** - removes beginning and trailing brackets

```
$widget_id = preg_replace(array('/^\[/','/\]$/'), '',$widget_text);
```

**str_replace()** - this removes brackets anywhere in the text

```
$widget_id = str_replace(array('[',']'), '',$widget_text);
```

**trim()** - trims brackets from beginning and end

```
$widget_id = trim($widget_text,'[]')
```

**substr()** - does the same as trim() (assuming the widget text does not include any closing brackets within the text)

```
$widget_id = substr($widget_text,
                    $start = strspn($widget_text, '['),
                    strcspn($widget_text, ']') - $start
             );
```

Comment: @Scott B: np, just figured you already knew _how_ to use str_replace

Comment: Yep: I might actually like the trim option in this case. Its trivial either way as the good Col. indicates.

Answer (score 6):

```
$widget_id = str_replace('[', '', str_replace(']', '', $widget_text));
```

Comment: `$widget_id = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $widget_text);` better

Answer (score 1):

If the brackets are always at first and last position, use this:

```
$widget_id = substr($widget_text, 1, strlen($widget_text)-2);
```

I think this is a faster way...

Comment: Fastest way: $widget_text = 'widget_and-some-text'; :P

Comment: But jokes aside, it should be faster than the equivalent preg_replace(array('/^\[/','/\]$/'), '',$widget_text)