# How to remove all preceding zero after whitespace in whole string

Tags: php

i want to remove all preceding zero of my string.  my string is

```
$schoolname="P.S. 003 Charrette School";
```

and i have to remove all preceding zero,special character and white space from my string and after that i want this output

```
 $schoolname="PS3CharretteSchool";
```

i have used str_replace but it is not useful in dynamic string 
suppose if string is like this

```
$schoolname="P S 003 Charrette School"
```

```
        $s = str_replace(' 0', '', $schoolname);
         $st = str_replace('.000', '', $s);
        $str = str_replace('.00', '', $st);
        $str1 = str_replace('.0', '', $str);
        $str2 = str_replace(',', '', $str1);
        $str3 = str_replace('-', '', $str2);
        $str4 = str_replace('/', '', $str3);
        $str5 = str_replace('&', '', $str4);
        $str6 = str_replace('=', '', $str5);
        $str7 = str_replace('!', '', $str6);
        $str8 = str_replace('@', '', $str7);
        $str9 = str_replace('#', '', $str8);
        $str10 = str_replace('$', '', $str9);
        $str11 = str_replace('%', '', $str10);
        $str12 = str_replace('^', '', $str11);
        $str13 = str_replace('*', '', $str12);
        $str14 = str_replace('(', '', $str13);
        $str15 = str_replace(')', '', $str14);
        $str16 = str_replace('_', '', $str15);
        $str17 = str_replace('+', '', $str16);
         $str18 = str_replace(' ', '', $str17);
         $str19 = str_replace('.', '', $str18);

         echo $str19;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433754/methods-to-remove-specific-characters-from-string

Comment: Will your sting always be start with "P S" and then some numbers?  Or could it be other letters?

Comment: yes other letter also come it is dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  $string = 'P.S. 000030 Charrette School';
$array = explode(' ',$string);             
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    $array[$key] = ltrim($value,'0');
}
$schoolname = implode(' ',$array);

$newString = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $schoolname);

echo $newString;
```

Comment: yes it is useful but it fails when my string is like
P.S. 000030 Charrette School
here it removes 0 after 3 like
PS3CharretteSchool
i want this PS30CharretteSchool

Comment: @saurabh2836: He *did* say `preceding zero`.

Comment: you can explode string before and use ltrim function in loop ltrim($str, '0'); after that implode and use my regural

Comment: @saurabh2836 it work just for this template string, this is just fast solution.