# How to replace a character with white space from a given string in php?

Tags: php, regex

```
$country = preg_replace(array('/^\[/','/\]$/'), '',$country);
```

That will remove brackets anywhere in the text as per this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433754/methods-to-remove-specific-characters-from-string)

But lets say we have:

```
United_arab_emirates
```

How can we do it in order to have it as:

`United Arab Emirates` ?

**NOTE:** Not a php guru here*

This is what I have and tried (thanks to one of the answers here)

```
$custom_country = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-3');
$custom_country = htmlspecialchars_decode($custom_country);
$custom_country = nl2br($custom_country);
$country = preg_replace(array('_'), ' ',$country); 
echo ucfirst($custom_country);
```

Result still `United_arab_emirates`

Comment: If possible, I'd suggest adding a regex tag to this question as it's largely a regular expression question.

Comment: @alaric done, :)

Comment: @rob.m that `preg_replace` usage is incorrect. PHP requires delimiters, php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quickest way would be two steps:

1. replace underscores with spaces
2. uppercase first letter of each word

Code:

```
$country = str_replace('_', ' ', $country);
$country = ucwords($country);
```

Comment: @rob.m you stated that your desired output was "United Arab Emirates" correct? Each of the three words is capitalized (first letter of each word, that is. ucfirst would only capitalize the first letter of the whole string which in your case would do nothing since United is already capitalized) EDIT: glad to help! Many times it's best to break down a problem into simple steps. :)

Comment: You are correct, deleted the comment you are referring to, it is perfect as you did it. Thanks a lot, saved me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$country = preg_replace(array('[_]'), ' ',$country);
```

or you can just use string replace

```
$country = str_replace("_"," ",$country);
```

Comment: do we still need the brackets?

Comment: Yes, the brackets mean a *group* of characters, in this case it's only the underscore!

Comment: That `preg_replace` isn't using a character class, those brackets are delimiters. The array also is unneeded. `It is also possible to use bracket style delimiters where the opening and closing brackets are the starting and ending delimiter, respectively. (), {}, [] and <> are all valid bracket style delimiter pairs.`

Answer (score 1):

If `_` is the only extra character you need to replace you could use `str_replace`:

```
$country = str_replace("_", " ", $country);
```

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php