# how to check if a string contains something in the beginning of it or the end using php?

Tags: php

I have an array with some values that contain "-" at the end or the beginning of the value. I am trying to remove the dash from those values using php. I have looked for answers online `str_replace` will replace every occurrence in the string. `str_pos` will just return the position of the occurrence. I have seen solutions using ruby and python but did not see one for php.

Sample values:

```
yourname
-yourname
yourname-
-your-name-
-your-name
your-name-
```

Should return:

```
yourname
yourname
yourname
your-name
your-name
your-name
```

Comment: You can find an answer for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433754/methods-to-remove-specific-characters-from-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = ['-yourname','yourname-','-yourname-'];
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value){
    $arr[$key] = trim($value, '-');
}
print_r($arr);
```

Or check it out working at https://3v4l.org/kEPR7

Read up on [trim](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

try the function ltrim() using the second parameter:

`$string = ltrim($input, '-');`

--
sorry, you said also at the end: trim() would be the function you need.

btw: could it happen there's more than 1 dash at the beginning or end of the input?