# Strip specific characters from post request

Tags: php, security

Example code written in php

```
$input = $_POST["password"]; 
$password = "secret"; 

if (strcmp($input, $password) == 0) { 
echo("$password"); 
}
```

To bypass the function shown on the code above, I can just submit password[]=

Just for educational purposes. Is there any way I can strip [ and ] characters from $_POST queries?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. If you are using `password[]=` to set the value for `$_POST["password"]` then you are instructing PHP that `$_POST["password"]` is an array. If you only want it to be a string you should use `password=`. Can you provide some more context?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to strip [] from $_POST array, to prevent someone who can intercept the post request and submitting password[]= as his input.

Comment: Found an answer here on stackoverflow that shows different ways to clean your string from different characters and cases that could good. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7128879/6041623

Comment: If you are concerned about a man in the middle attack (someone intercepting the post request) then you should only allow a password submission via HTTPS. (Read about this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Comment: @neuromatter I'm not concerned about MITM, and I'm aware of the countermeasures. I just want to know if PHP can strip the specific characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Methods to remove specific characters from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433754/methods-to-remove-specific-characters-from-string)

Comment: It's just a string. You'd use the same method that you'd use for any other string. The fact that it came from `$_POST` isn't really relevant.

Comment: While asking how to remove characters from a string is a thing, is is incredibly alerting that it has anything to do with passwords and security. You should not, ever, not even for "educational purposes", be thinking about password validation using string comparison. [Please learn about the built-in password api.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php)

Comment: @neuromatter, I think the only context we need is that `strcmp` returns 0 when you pass it an array (along with a warning). The bypass has nothing to do with filtering [], but with a function that returns a valid result on invalid input. A simple if `is_string()` will improve the code, but obv. there are many better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip any characters you want out of a string. If you want to perform this for the entire `$_POST` array then you can wrap either option below in a `foreach` loop.

If you are looking for a non-regex option you can use `str_replace`: http://php.net/str_replace

```
$input = 'string [with] brackets';

echo str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $input);
```

Example: https://eval.in/853491

Or if you are looking for a regex option you can use `preg_replace`: http://php.net/preg_replace

```
$input = 'string [with] brackets';

echo preg_replace('/\[|\]/', '', $input);
```

Example: https://eval.in/853492